# How to init Configuration Object from XML?

Tags: c#, .net

How to init the object of System.Configuration.Configuration from XML file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20952/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-system-configuration-configuration-instance-based-on-arb

Comment: could you maybe be more specific? Add an example perhaps?