# How to load Configuration from a string

Tags: c#, configuration

**Update 1** - The suggested approach won't work, because of I need to load the whole Config, it's a contract between my code and external call (see my questions). The technique won't work at least because of Configuration is sealed.

I have and Xml string representing an entire config file as input and need to create an instance of `System.Configuration.Configuration` out of it for passing into an external routine, which performs:

```
ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup(configuration);
```

as part of its logic.

Wonder if it's possible to do it w/out using a file system (Can't call App domain for any direct manipulations neither).

Comment: I think here is [the answer for your question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/704817/3107178)

Comment: Almost a copy, I'll try the technique for the entire Configuration, see what what's come out...